# Accessing AdvertisingIdClient in Play Services 9.4.0

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-play, google-play-services

I added play-services-ads to my project, but apparently it doesn't contain

com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.

which of the following libraries do I have to include?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AdvertisingIdClient` is in `play-services-ads-identifier`.

Comment: Thanks. Do  you know how can I compile it in `build.gradle`? My project is an java sdk and I use Java gradle plugin. I tried,

`compile (name:'play-services-basement/9.4.0/play-services-basement-9.4.0', ext:'aar')`

It compiles successfully but fails in `:compileJava` with package not found.

Comment: Pretty sure all of the Play services dependencies use parts of the Android SDK so they'd need to be used in an Android application or library project.

Comment: We used to use play-services-6.X and we used to import the Jar in our java project. So, now I need to extract the .aar, fetch the jar and include the same? I want to know if there is any automatic way to compile .aar file in gradle and add that as a library for my java project.

Comment: That sounds like a different question entirely (and not a supported way to use Google Play services AFAIK) - I'd suggest creating a new question for that.

Comment: AdvertisingIdClient has moved and it's now in play-services-ads-identifier